# Delphi Request.ContentFields.Values['something'] is not showing values on MIME data

Tags: delphi, post, indy, indy10, webbroker

In `TWebModule1.WebModule1WebActionItem1Action()`, using `Request.ContentFields.Values['content']` or any name, I cannot get any values from the `POST`, but if I use `Request.ContentFields.DelimitedText`, I will get the values. Where did I go wrong?

This is the values `DelimitedText` returned:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryHkgxkABfO4DL8g8Q,"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""name""",NEWTEST,------WebKitFormBoundaryHkgxkABfO4DL8g8Q,"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""content""","{""resolution""",D,",""symbol_type""",stock,",""exchange""",IDX,",""listed_exchange""",IDX,",""symbol""",BBCA,",""short_name""",BBCA,",""legs""",[{\,"symbol\"":\""","BCA\"",\""","ro_symbol\"":\""","BCA\""}]""",id,":2,""name""",NEWTEST,",""description""",,",""charts_symbols""",{\,"1\"":{\""","ymbol\"":\""","BCA\""}}""",is_realtime,":""1""",content,":""{\""","ame\"":\""","EWTEST\"",\""","ayout\"":\""","\"",\""","harts\"":[{\""","anes\"":[{\""","ources\"":[{\""","ype\"":\""","ainSeries\"",\""","d\"":\""","NUxsv\"",\""","tate\"":{\""","tyle\"":8,\""","sdShowDividends\"":true,\""","sdShowSplits\"":true,\""","sdShowEarnings\"":true,\""","sdShowBreaks\"":false,\""","sdFlagSize\"":2,\""","howCountdown\"":false,\""","idAsk\"":{\""","isible\"":false,\""","ineStyle\"":1,\""","ineWidth\"":1,\""","idLineColor\"":\""","2962FF\"",\""","skLineColor\"":\""","F7525F\""},\""","rePostMarket\"":{\""","isible\"":true,\""","ineStyle\"":1,\""","ineWidth\"":1,\""","reMarketColor\"":\""","fb8c00\"",\""","ostMarketColor\"":\""","2962FF\""},\""","ighLowAvgPrice\"":{\""","ighLowPriceLinesVisible\"":false,\""","ighLowPriceLabelsVisible\"":false,\""","verageClosePriceLineVisible\"":false,\""","verageClosePriceLabelVisible\"":false},\""","howInDataWindow\"":true,\""","isible\"":true,\""","howPriceLine\"":true,\""","riceLineWidth\"":1,\""","riceLineColor\"":\""",",\","baseLineColor\"":\""","B2B5BE\"",\""","howPrevClosePriceLine\"":false,\""","revClosePriceLineWidth\"":1,\""","revClosePriceLineColor\"":\""","gba( 85, 85, 85, 1)\"",\""","inTick\"":\""","efault\"",\""","ividendsAdjustment\"":{},\""","ackAdjustment\"":false,\""","ettlementAsClose\"":true,\""","essionId\"":\""","egular\"",\""","essVis\"":false,\""","tatusViewStyle\"":{\""","ontSize\"":17,\""","howExchange\"":true,\""","howInterval\"":true,\""","ymbolTextSource\"":\""","escription\"",\""","howSymbolAsDescription\"":false},\""","andleStyle\"":{\""","pColor\"":\""","53b987\"",\""","ownColor\"":\""","eb4d5c\"",\""","rawWick\"":true,\""","rawBorder\"":true,\""","orderColor\"":\""","378658\"",\""","orderUpColor\"":\""","53b987\"",\""","orderDownColor\"":\""","eb4d5c\"",\""","ickColor\"":\""","737375\"",\""","ickUpColor\"":\""","a9cdd3\"",\""","ickDownColor\"":\""","f5a6ae\"",\""","arColorsOnPrevClose\"":false,\""","rawBody\"":true},\""","ollowCandleStyle\"":{\""","pColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","ownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","rawWick\"":true,\""","rawBorder\"":true,\""","orderColor\"":\""","gba( 55, 134, 88, 1)\"",\""","orderUpColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","orderDownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","ickColor\"":\""","gba( 115, 115, 117, 1)\"",\""","ickUpColor\"":\""","gba( 169, 220, 195, 1)\"",\""","ickDownColor\"":\""","gba( 245, 166, 174, 1)\"",\""","rawBody\"":true},\""","aStyle\"":{\""","pColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","ownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","rawWick\"":true,\""","rawBorder\"":true,\""","orderColor\"":\""","gba( 55, 134, 88, 1)\"",\""","orderUpColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","orderDownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","ickColor\"":\""","gba( 115, 115, 117, 1)\"",\""","ickUpColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","ickDownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","howRealLastPrice\"":false,\""","arColorsOnPrevClose\"":false,\""","nputs\"":{},\""","nputInfo\"":{},\""","rawBody\"":true},\""","arStyle\"":{\""","pColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","ownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","arColorsOnPrevClose\"":false,\""","ontDrawOpen\"":false,\""","hinBars\"":true},\""","iloStyle\"":{\""","olor\"":\""","2962FF\"",\""","howBorders\"":true,\""","orderColor\"":\""","2962FF\"",\""","howLabels\"":true,\""","abelColor\"":\""","2962FF\"",\""","ontSize\"":7,\""","rawBody\"":true},\""","ineStyle\"":{\""","olor\"":\""","gba( 60, 120, 216, 1)\"",\""","inestyle\"":0,\""","inewidth\"":1,\""","riceSource\"":\""","lose\"",\""","tyleType\"":2},\""","reaStyle\"":{\""","olor1\"":\""","gba( 96, 96, 144, 0.5)\"",\""","olor2\"":\""","gba( 1, 246, 245, 0.5)\"",\""","inecolor\"":\""","gba( 0, 148, 255, 1)\"",\""","inestyle\"":0,\""","inewidth\"":1,\""","riceSource\"":\""","lose\"",\""","ransparency\"":50},\""","enkoStyle\"":{\""","pColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","ownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","orderUpColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","orderDownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","pColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 169, 220, 195, 1)\"",\""","ownColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 245, 166, 174, 1)\"",\""","orderUpColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 169, 220, 195, 1)\"",\""","orderDownColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 245, 166, 174, 1)\"",\""","ickUpColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","ickDownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","nputs\"":{\""","ource\"":\""","lose\"",\""","ources\"":\""","lose\"",\""","oxSize\"":3,\""","tyle\"":\""","TR\"",\""","trLength\"":14,\""","icks\"":true},\""","nputInfo\"":{\""","ource\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","ource\""},\""","ources\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","ource\""},\""","oxSize\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","ox size\""},\""","tyle\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","tyle\""},\""","trLength\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","TR Length\""},\""","icks\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","icks\""}}},\""","bStyle\"":{\""","pColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","ownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","orderUpColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","orderDownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","pColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 169, 220, 195, 1)\"",\""","ownColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 245, 166, 174, 1)\"",\""","orderUpColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 169, 220, 195, 1)\"",\""","orderDownColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 245, 166, 174, 1)\"",\""","nputs\"":{\""","ource\"":\""","lose\"",\""","b\"":3},\""","nputInfo\"":{\""","ource\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","ource\""},\""","b\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","umber of line\""}}},\""","agiStyle\"":{\""","pColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","ownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","pColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 169, 220, 195, 1)\"",\""","ownColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 245, 166, 174, 1)\"",\""","nputs\"":{\""","ource\"":\""","lose\"",\""","tyle\"":\""","TR\"",\""","trLength\"":14,\""","eversalAmount\"":1},\""","nputInfo\"":{\""","ource\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","ource\""},\""","tyle\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","tyle\""},\""","trLength\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","TR Length\""},\""","eversalAmount\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","eversal amount\""}}},\""","nfStyle\"":{\""","pColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","ownColor\"":\""","gba( 255, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","pColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 169, 220, 195, 1)\"",\""","ownColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 245, 166, 174, 1)\"",\""","nputs\"":{\""","ources\"":\""","lose\"",\""","eversalAmount\"":3,\""","oxSize\"":1,\""","tyle\"":\""","TR\"",\""","trLength\"":14,\""","neStepBackBuilding\"":false},\""","nputInfo\"":{\""","ources\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","ource\""},\""","oxSize\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","ox size\""},\""","eversalAmount\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","eversal amount\""},\""","tyle\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","tyle\""},\""","trLength\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","TR Length\""},\""","neStepBackBuilding\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","ne step back building\""}}},\""","aselineStyle\"":{\""","aselineColor\"":\""","gba( 117, 134, 150, 1)\"",\""","opFillColor1\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 0.1)\"",\""","opFillColor2\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 0.1)\"",\""","ottomFillColor1\"":\""","gba( 235, 77, 92, 0.1)\"",\""","ottomFillColor2\"":\""","gba( 235, 77, 92, 0.1)\"",\""","opLineColor\"":\""","gba( 83, 185, 135, 1)\"",\""","ottomLineColor\"":\""","gba( 235, 77, 92, 1)\"",\""","opLineWidth\"":1,\""","ottomLineWidth\"":1,\""","riceSource\"":\""","lose\"",\""","ransparency\"":50,\""","aseLevelPercentage\"":50},\""","angeStyle\"":{\""","pColor\"":\""","22AB94\"",\""","ownColor\"":\""","F7525F\"",\""","hinBars\"":true,\""","pColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 169, 220, 195, 1)\"",\""","ownColorProjection\"":\""","gba( 245, 166, 174, 1)\"",\""","nputs\"":{\""","ange\"":10,\""","hantomBars\"":false},\""","nputInfo\"":{\""","ange\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","ange\""},\""","hantomBars\"":{\""","ame\"":\""","hantom bars\""}}},\""","ilentIntervalChange\"":false,\""","ymbol\"":\""","BCA\"",\""","hortName\"":\""","BCA\"",\""","imeframe\"":\""",",\","onWidget\"":false,\""","nterval\"":\""","\"",\""","nitId\"":null,\""","urrencyId\"":\""","DR\"",\""","howSessions\"":false,\""","riceAxisProperties\"":{\""","utoScale\"":true,\""","utoScaleDisabled\"":false,\""","ockScale\"":false,\""","ercentage\"":false,\""","ercentageDisabled\"":false,\""","og\"":false,\""","ogDisabled\"":false,\""","lignLabels\"":true,\""","sInverted\"":false,\""","ndexedTo100\"":false}},\""","order\"":0,\""","aStyle\"":{\""","tudyId\"":\""","arSetHeikenAshi@tv-basicstudies-60\""},\""","enkoStyle\"":{\""","tudyId\"":\""","arSetRenko@tv-prostudies-40\""},\""","bStyle\"":{\""","tudyId\"":\""","arSetPriceBreak@tv-prostudies-34\""},\""","agiStyle\"":{\""","tudyId\"":\""","arSetKagi@tv-prostudies-34\""},\""","nfStyle\"":{\""","tudyId\"":\""","arSetPnF@tv-prostudies-34\""},\""","angeStyle\"":{\""","tudyId\"":\""","arSetRange@tv-basicstudies-72\""}},{\""","ype\"":\""","tudy_Volume\"",\""","d\"":\""","InSIU\"",\""","tate\"":{\""","tyles\"":{\""","ol\"":{\""","inestyle\"":0,\""","inewidth\"":1,\""","lottype\"":5,\""","rackPrice\"":false,\""","ransparency\"":50,\""","isible\"":true,\""","olor\"":\""","000080\"",\""","istogramBase\"":0,\""","oinPoints\"":false,\""","itle\"":\""","olume\""},\""","ol_ma\"":{\""","inestyle\"":0,\""","inewidth\"":1,\""","lottype\"":0,\""","rackPrice\"":false,\""","ransparency\"":0,\""","isible\"":false,\""","olor\"":\""","2196f3\"",\""","istogramBase\"":0,\""","oinPoints\"":false,\""","itle\"":\""","olume MA\""},\""","moothedMA\"":{\""","inestyle\"":0,\""","inewidth\"":1,\""","lottype\"":0,\""","rackPrice\"":false,\""","ransparency\"":0,\""","isible\"":false,\""","olor\"":\""","2196f3\"",\""","istogramBase\"":0,\""","oinPoints\"":false,\""","itle\"":\""","moothed MA\""}},\""","alettes\"":{\""","olumePalette\"":{\""","olors\"":{\""","\"":{\""","olor\"":\""","F7525F\"",\""","idth\"":1,\""","tyle\"":0,\""","ame\"":\""","alling\""},\""","\"":{\""","olor\"":\""","22AB94\"",\""","idth\"":1,\""","tyle\"":0,\""","ame\"":\""","rowing\""}}}},\""","nputs\"":{\""","howMA\"":false,\""","ength\"":20,\""","ol_prev_close\"":false,\""","ymbol\"":\""",",\","smoothingLine\"":\""","MA\"",\""","moothingLength\"":9},\""","recision\"":\""","efault\"",\""","ands\"":{},\""","rea\"":{},\""","raphics\"":{},\""","howInDataWindow\"":true,\""","isible\"":true,\""","howLegendValues\"":true,\""","howLabelsOnPriceScale\"":true,\""","lots\"":{\""","\"":{\""","d\"":\""","ol\"",\""","ype\"":\""","ine\""},\""","\"":{\""","d\"":\""","olumePalette\"",\""","alette\"":\""","olumePalette\"",\""","arget\"":\""","ol\"",\""","ype\"":\""","olorer\""},\""","\"":{\""","isible\"":true,\""","utureOnly\"":true,\""","reaks\"":{\""","olor\"":\""","gba(85, 85, 85, 1)\"",\""","isible\"":false,\""","tyle\"":2,\""","idth\"":1}},\""","radingProperties\"":{\""","howPositions\"":true,\""","ositionPL\"":{\""","isibility\"":true,\""","isplay\"":0},\""","howOrders\"":true,\""","howExecutions\"":true,\""","howReverse\"":true,\""","orizontalAlignment\"":2,\""","xtendLeft\"":true,\""","ineLength\"":5,\""","ineWidth\"":1,\""","ineStyle\"":2},\""","riceScaleSelectionStrategyName\"":\""","uto\""},\""","ineToolsGroups\"":{\""","roups\"":[]},\""","ersion\"":3,\""","imezone\"":\""","tc/UTC\"",\""","essions\"":{\""","roperties\"":{\""","raphics\"":{\""","ackgrounds\"":{\""","utOfSession\"":{\""","olor\"":\""","2962FF\"",\""","ransparency\"":92,\""","isible\"":false},\""","reMarket\"":{\""","olor\"":\""","FF9800\"",\""","ransparency\"":92,\""","isible\"":false},\""","ostMarket\"":{\""","olor\"":\""","2962FF\"",\""","ransparency\"":92,\""","isible\"":false}},\""","ertlines\"":{\""","essBreaks\"":{\""","olor\"":\""","4985e7\"",\""","tyle\"":2,\""","isible\"":false,\""","idth\"":1}}}}},\""","houldBeSavedEvenIfHidden\"":true,\""","hartId\"":\""","\""}]}""",------WebKitFormBoundaryHkgxkABfO4DL8g8Q,"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""symbol""",BBCA,------WebKitFormBoundaryHkgxkABfO4DL8g8Q,"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""resolution""",D,------WebKitFormBoundaryHkgxkABfO4DL8g8Q--
```

Comment: I just found out this is a multipart messages, how to decode it?

Answer (score 1):

I have been googling the whole web, mostly outdated answer from years ago and I don't find any proper easy way to parse it, but I found my own manual way, please anyone, have a better way to parse please share. thanks.

```
      LBoundary := ExtractHeaderSubItem(Request.ContentType, 'boundary', QuoteHTTP);
      tmpstring :=  Request.Content;
      tmpstring := trim(tmpstring);
      i := Pos('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"', tmpstring);
      j := Pos('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"', tmpstring);
      k := j - i;
      tmpstring := (Copy(tmpstring, i, k));
      tmpstring := StringReplace(tmpstring, 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
      tmpstring := StringReplace(tmpstring, 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
      tmpstring := StringReplace(tmpstring, '--'+LBoundary, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
      tmpstring := StringReplace(tmpstring, #13#10, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
      tmpstring := StringReplace(tmpstring, #32, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
      tmpstring := StringReplace(tmpstring, #9, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
      name:= tmpstring;
```